Why did Leta offer sex to Milo?
In Cry Macho (2021), at 12:36, when Leta first sees Mike Milo, she mocks him in Spanish, saying:
Leta: "¿Este es el hombre que manda? ¿Un viejo cowboy acabado? ¿A robarse a mi hijo? Eres un hombre muy viejo."

Translated into English, this means:
Leta: "This is the man he sends? A broken-down old cowboy? To steal my son? You are a very old man."
This dialogue emphasizes her disdain and disbelief at Mike's age and appearance, reinforcing her contemptuous attitude toward him.
Therefore, there seemed to be no apparent reason for offering sex to an old and unattractive guy like Mike Milo.

What was the reason that Leta decided to offer sex to Mike Milo?

I don't think the comment (whether or not it was actually what she thought) and offering sex are mutually exclusive. (By the way, I also don't think "disbelief" is the right word :). Can you tell us more about the context? Could it be that Leta was lying, or is attracted to ugly/old men, or likes to pretend she doesn't like people she's attracted to, or just feels like having sex anyway, &c.?
